# Ruby on rails: How are responsibilities separated in a rails application with complex business logic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications

I'm moving from a .NET driven web architecture to a ruby on rails stack. I'm used to having a web layer for rendering the webpages with the css/Javascripts needed, a seperate app layer that takes care of all the business logic, ORM and DAL layer and a database for persistence.

Now how does all translate in rails?

The models seem to do all the work with respect business logic, ORM and data access. So do complex applications like twitter not use a separate app layer for business logic? Is the model everything with respect to complex logic? If so, isn't it difficult to move everything as a service if you want to expose services to others in the future?

Please throw some light on how things work in a complex web app.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of one of the difficulties you are seeing? You'd access a service through a controller action. I'm not seeing why the consumer should care what is implemented where in the provider.

Comment: True. My query is more regarding how complex websites would be implemented. Does ActiveRecord work in the long term for a complex web app like Twitter with its own sophisticated set of needs?

Or is the business logic moved as a separate layer and rails used to take care of the routing, actions and views? Does convention hinder in such cases?

Comment: Thin Controller, Fat Model is more of an unwritten rule than a convention. You can do it the other way round, but you'd have to do a lot of manual work or write your own scaffolding etc. There's no right answer to your question, once you choose or need to start getting outside of rails comfort zone. There's no particular reason why you couldn't have one site providing simple views through and them consuming them as xml, yaml, json etc to provide a a business logic layer. It's more about should you than can you. THink you might be better off asking this on programmers.stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

Rails is a full stack MVC framework and it's M part is built with the Active Record pattern. Basically the model contains the persistence layer and the business logic.

I invite you to read the EAA catalog for more informations : [EAA ActiveRecord](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html)

Most of the persistence part is hidden behind the framework, so you shouldn't have too much of it. However, if you have a complex business logic you can split your models in two parts (persistence/business). Your ActiveRecord::Base class will have the persistence part and your new class the business logic. But if you do so it's not an Active Record anymore, but a Datamapper.

Speaking of Datamapper, there is an altenative to ActiveRecord called DataMapper, but I've never tested it. [DataMapper website](http://datamapper.org)

> Isn't it difficult to move everything as a service if you want to
>   expose services to others in the future?

If service means webservice the answer is no. The only thing you would have to do is to create a controller dedicated for your webservice. Most of time people lose the DRYness in their applications because they put too much logic in controllers, but if your models have been made properly it should not be a concern.

Answer (score 0):

you can build complex business logic separated from models and controller using [rails_workflow gem](https://github.com/madzhuga/rails_workflow).